# How do I get my .log file into a database or suitable format for a database

Tags: mysql, sed, insert, string-parsing

The layout of my log file is as follows:

```
 08/30 06:30:40  0000:00:04 T992    **** 01865888888 860444         ST992                                  101   T1011                1865888888         Y1016969 A                                            
 08/30 06:35:09  0000:00:03 T992    **** 01865888888               E                                       101   T1011                1865888888         G1013976 A                                            
 08/30 06:36:50  0000:00:03 T992    **** 01865888888               E                                       101   T1011                1865888888         W1017933 A                                            
 08/30 06:48:34  0000:00:16 516332  **** 516330                    I 516330                                101
```

How do I display all Columns evenly so I can easily import this data into a database.

I have tried SED for windows to remove multiple spaces and insert comma instead but still does not line up the columns I need all the 101 for example to be inline and all the dates to be inline etc.

Anyone help?

Comment: You don't want `sed`, you want `cut`

Answer (score 0):

Here, I started it for you:

```
sed -r 's/(.{5}) (.{8})  (.{10}) (.{6})/"\1","\2","\3","\4"/'
```

This will extract the first 4 fields.
Calculate the number of columns, put in `(.{<number>})`
Add the spaces
get the result with `,"\<field number>"`

Here's my test

```
echo "08/30 06:48:34  0000:00:16 516332  **** 516330                    I 516330 " | sed -r 's/(.{5}) (.{8})  (.{10}) (.{6})/"\1","\2","\3","\4"/'
```

Comment: Brilliant answer, and I believe this has solved my issue ( still working on it at the moment). I was amazed how quick my question god answered too. thanks for your time in looking at this. I have tried and tried many a things out to resolved this wish I asked for help sooner. :-)

Comment: How do you work out from a  top row having a 11 digit number then a a digit number and the second line having a 1 digit number then a 11 digit number. because SED command I'm using above just doesn't recgnoise it only have 1 character......
08/30,06:17:48,0000:00:36,T992  ,0001 01865868888 8688888         ST992                                  101   T1011                1865868888         Y1014798 A                                            
 08/30,06:17:48,0000:00:36,T992  ,     1 01865868888

Comment: ugh. Okaaay. How do you feel about a quick perl or php script instead :-)

Comment: Php would be better. Just somethig that will make it all have a comma rather that un even spaces. Or c# if anyone can assist. Just not managed to find anything worth while to help

Comment: end result weather it be PHP or SED command I need the file to look like:

 08/30,06:17:48,0000:00:36 T992,0001,01865860888,860444,ST992,101,T1011,186586888,Y101798, A                                            

08/30,06:17:48,0000:00:36,T992,    ,1,018658888,AST992,101,T101,Y1018888,B